# Error a la hora de guardar datos en Cake - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-bake

Tengo 2 tablas, `roles` y `operations` y se relacionan en una tercera tabla `operations_roles`. Éste es mi archivo de migración:

```
$table = $this->table('roles');
        $table ->addColumn('user_id','integer')->addForeignKey('user_id','users','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->addColumn('rolname','string')
->addColumn('roldescripcion','string')
->create();       

$table = $this->table('operations');
 $table ->addColumn('user_id','integer')->addForeignKey('user_id','users','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->addColumn('opename','string')
->addColumn('opedescripcion','string') 
->create();

$table = $this->table('operations_roles');
$table ->addColumn('operation_id','integer')->addForeignKey('operation_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->addColumn('role_id','integer')->addForeignKey('role_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->create();
```

Todo lo demás lo creo con [Bake][1].

Entonces, lo que pasa cuando voy a crear un *rol* y le voy a asignar *operaciones* ya creadas es que al principio lo hace bien pero después de la tercera creación de un rol me lanza este error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prueba1`.`operations_roles`, CONSTRAINT `operations_roles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `operations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Y la verdad es que no entiendo, si guarda 2 roles con sus respectivas operaciones, ¿por qué cuando voy a crear otro me devuelve este error?

EJEMPLO:
primero creo 2 operaciones Operación 1 y Operación 2. Cuando voy a crear el rol Rol 1 le asigno las operaciones 1 y 2. Creo otro rol Rol 2 con la Operación 1 y Rol 3 con la Operación 2. Cuando voy a editar o add otro rol con operaciones me devuelve ese error. Ojo si creo un rol solo sin operaciones no hay problema. El problema está cuando se guarda en operations_roles

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando un ejemplo de 3 roles que estés creando y cómo para generar el error?

Comment: Listo ya lo coloqué en la pregunta

Comment: Nadie sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, viendo la fecha no creo que te sirva de mucho, pero...

```
$table = $this->table('operations_roles');
$table->addColumn('operation_id','integer')
->addForeignKey('operation_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->addColumn('role_id','integer')
->addForeignKey('role_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
->create();
```

Se supone que esta tabla es la que se genera de una relacion de muchos a muchos entre **operations** y **roles**, por lo tanto, debe tener la clave primaria de ambos, en este caso, agregas la clave primara de la tabla **operations**

```
->addColumn('operation_id','integer')
->addForeignKey('operation_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
```

Y luego agregas la clave primaria de la tabla **roles**

```
->addColumn('role_id','integer')
->addForeignKey('role_id','operations','id',array('delete'=>'CASCADE','update'=>'CASCADE'))
```

Pero si te fijas, le indicas que la tabla es **operations** y no **roles**, sugiero cambiar esta linea por la que corresponda a la de la tabla roles.